# precache multiple svg assets in flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, flutter-dependencies

I have 15-20 svgs in my asset which i want to precache. Currently am doing it in my void main.
**Code:-**

```
try{
    Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/1.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/2.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/3.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/4.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/5.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/6.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/7.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/8.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/9.svg'), null,),
Future.wait([
      precachePicture(ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/10.svg'), null,),
  }
  catch(e){print(e);}
```

So, my question is what would be the better way to cache them i.e. cache assets in my main or in my splashscreen or like half-half  i.e on both. Secondly, will it take more time for my app to render first frame if i cache multiple images in my main?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but your usage of `Future.wait` is wrong. It takes an iterator as argument, so you only need one `Future.wait` for the entire preload. Example:

```
final svgs = ['assets/1.svg', 'assets/2.svg', ]; // all the svg that needs preloading
final promises = svgs.map((e) => precachePicture(
          ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, e), null));
await Future.wait(promises);
```

I would recommend you to do this in a splash screen instead of in `main`. Because if you do this before the UI is rendered it will give the impression that your app is hanging (white screen), so at least show something nice so the user has the feeling that your app starts faster.